# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined for my todolis

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my todo list to display my work on the page but it doesnt want to show getting all these errors.

I want the user input for the task to shows as a block Cant seems to figure out what's wrong I looked at the type of text but then that's correct I don know if the content/user input is not being read properly as a string or what.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          noteText: "",
          notes: []
      };
  }
  updateNoteText(noteText) {
      this.setState({ noteText: noteText.target.value });
  }
  addNote() {
      if (this.state.noteText === "") {
          return;
      }

      let notesArr = this.notes;
      notesArr.push(this.state.noteText);
      this.setState({ noteText: "" });
      this.textInput.focus();
  }

  handlekeyPress = event => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {}
  };
  deleteNote(index) {
      let notesArr = this.state.notes;
      notesArr.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ notes: notesArr });
  }
  render() {
      let notes = this.state.notes.map((val, key) => {
          return (
              <Todo key={key} text={val} deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)} />
          );
      });

      return (
          <div className="container">
          <div className="header">React Todo List</div>
          <div className="btn" onClick={this.addNote.bind(this)}>
            +
          </div>
          {notes}
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={input => {
              this.textInput = input;
            }}
            className="textInput"
            value={this.state.noteText}
            onChange={noteText => this.updateNoteText(noteText)}
            onKeyPress={this.handlekeyPress.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this.notes is undefined

Comment: `let notesArr = this.notes` should be `let notesArr = this.state.notes`

Comment: Plus, you're not supposed to push to an array that's part of `state` directly. Use `this.setState({ noteText: "", notes: [...this.state.notes, this.state.noteText] });` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should read:

```
 let notesArr = this.state.notes;
```

rather than

```
 let notesArr = this.notes;
```

It's literally saying that this.notes is undefined.

Comment: This is the direct cause of the error but not the solution in the context of React.

Comment: @ChrisG what are you talking about mate?

Comment: If OP simply follows your answer, they will be pushing to `this.state.notes` right in the next line, something they are absolutely not supposed to do. This answer solves the issue at hand but completely ignores the bigger picture. (I guess this is why adiga posted your answer as a comment, one minute earlier)

Answer (score 1):

You should bind `this` or using arrow function and you have a little bug in your code as @Rob said.

So, just change this line `addNote() {` to `addNote = () => {` and `deleteNote(index) {` to `deleteNote = (index) => {`

Comment: This does not address the question; this should've been a comment. Plus, OP is using code like `deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)}` which will work fine. The issue isn't that `this` is pointing at the wrong thing.